# Detecting Line Splits

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I'm making an addin for ArcMap with ArcObjects and I want to detect when the user uses the split tool on a line feature. How can I achieve this?

```
    public StartUp()
    {
        var editor = MapHelpers.GetEditor(); //Returns the application's IEditor3
        var events = (editor as IEditEvents_Event);
        events.OnChangeFeature += (obj) =>
        {
        };
    }
```

So far all I can do is hook into the OnChangeFeature event and get the resulting IObject. I don't know where to go from here as the documentation is lacking.

Comment: I suspect split fires `OnCreateFeature` in addition to `OnChangeFeature`, so maybe test to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current tool and check for the Splitting Tool ID. If the user is using third party splitting tools, you can also include those IDs in the `splittingTools` collection.

```
        events.OnChangeFeature += (obj) =>
        {
            var splittingTools = new List<string> { /*Default Tool:*/ "{5609B740-112F-11D2-84A9-0000F875B9C6}" };
            var currentToolID = ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool.ID.Value;
            var isSplit = splittingTools.Contains(currentToolID);
        }
```

Comment: Be aware of what happens when the line feature participates in a geometric network and a point that participates in the same network splits the line when placed on it. (not a tool doing the split)